# Multiple bibliographies with multibbl

Tags: bibliographies

I successfully incorporated a bibliography with BibTeX (file exported from Zotero named Chapter_1.bib) and now I am trying by using the package [multibbl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl) since I will have multiple bibliographies (several per chapter). My code looks like as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multibbl}
\newbibliography{biblio1}

\begin{document}

Blablablablablablablablablabla \cite{biblio1}{einstein_1905} and \cite{biblio1}{einstein_1935}.

\bibliographystyle{biblio1}{plain}
\bibliography{biblio1}{Chapter_1}{References}

\end{document}
```

It does create a file biblio1.aux which contains:

```
\citation{einstein_1905}
\citation{einstein_1935}
\bibstyle{plain}
\bibdata{Chapter_1}
```

But I get the following error "This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Th
Process exited with error(s)"

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What does the `.blg` file say?  What is the content of the `einstein_1905` and `einstein_1935` bib entries?

Comment: Thank you! The bib file contains the following fields which are correctly filled out (tested successfully without multibbl package):


`@article{einstein_1905,
 title = {},
 volume = {},
 issn = {},
 url = {},
 doi = {},
 language = {en},
 number = {},
 urldate = {},
 journal = {},
 author = {},
 month = sep,
 year = {},
 pages = {},
 file = {}
}`

and same thing for `einstein_1935`

Where should I look after opening the .blg file please?

Comment: Opening the .blg with Texmaker delivers the following: "These.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file These.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file These.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file These.aux (There were 3 error messages)"
I should specify that my file is named "These.tex"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each `\newbibliography{foo}` command, [`multibbl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl) creates a new `.aux` file `foo.aux` which it records all citations of the form `\cite{foo}{<citation_key>}` in.

Rather than running `bibtex zzz` in order to compile citations for `zzz.tex` (using `zzz.aux`) as as you would do with a simple BibTeX example (and as most editors are configured to do when running BibTeX), the use of [`multibbl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl) requires running `bibtex foo` to collect citations from each `foo.aux` generated by a `\newbibliography{foo}`.

Instead of (re-)configuring your editor, it may be simplest to make the necessary `bibtex foo` calls from the command line.

Comment: Indeed the problem comes from BibTex calls! I changed the Quick build command and now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dai Bowen. Thanks a lot.