# using both multibbl and natbib?

Tags: bibliographies

In a book I have multiple bibliographies (several per chapter) and, with the help of Dai Bowen in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383538/multiple-bibliographies-with-multibbl), I successfully overcame that by using `multibbl` package but I now face an incompatibility with `natbib`.

Natbib allows me to properly format the text notably with the absolutely necessary `[longnamesfirst]` option and `\citep`, `\citealp`, `\citeauthor`, `\citeyear`, etc. commands.

Is there a workaround so these packages coexist or any idea how I could do otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, the packages will not naturally coexist [`multibbl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl) and [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) do various redefining of internal citation commands which are incompatible.

The sensible answer is that for multiple bibliographies, using [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) will probably be much easier, as it can easily handle multiple bibliographies (e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87439/106162)) and (with the `natbib` package option) will define all the commands like `\citeauthor` etc. and therefore has the capabilities of both  [`multibbl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl) and [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) in a single package.

The longer answer is that it does seem to be possible to get elements of the two packages working together, it's hardly elegant and unfortunately I haven't found a way to get `longnamesfirst` working so far.
The main incompatibility is in their redefinition of `\@citex`, [`multibbl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl) redefines it as

```
\def\@citex[#1]#2#3{%
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#3\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \@ifundefined{#2@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
        \write\csname #2@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}}%
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\hbox{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
```

which inserts an extra argument and swaps the default

```
\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
```

for

```
\@ifundefined{#2@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
\write\csname #2@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}}%
```

while [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) does `\let\@citex\NAT@citex` or `\let\@citex\NAT@citexnum` depending on package options.
We therefore need to insert the extra `.aux` file name argument into both of these.
The `\citeyear`, `\citeauthor`, and  commands in [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) don't rely on `\@citex` but instead have their own call which must also be adjusted to accept two arguments, the first being the `.aux` file name and the second the citation key.

Packaged together into one file, some of the necessary changes seem to be

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibexample.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}
\newbibliography{biblio1}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\makeatletter

\def\NAT@citex%
  [#1][#2]#3#4{\let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\let\NAT@nm\@empty\let\NAT@year\@empty
    \@for\@citeb:=#4\do
    {\edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \@ifundefined{#3@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
    \write\csname #3@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}}%
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{\@citea%
       {\reset@font\bfseries ?}\NAT@citeundefined
                 \PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
     {\hyper@natlinkstart{\@citeb}%
     \let\NAT@last@nm=\NAT@nm\let\NAT@last@yr=\NAT@year
     \NAT@parse{\@citeb}\ifNAT@full\let\NAT@nm\NAT@all@names\else
       \let\NAT@nm\NAT@name\fi
     \ifNAT@swa
       \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep
          \ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year \NAT@exlab\else\unskip\ \NAT@date\fi
       \else\@citea{\NAT@nm}\NAT@aysep
       \ \NAT@date \fi \def\@citea{\NAT@sep\ }%
     \else
       \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep\ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
         \NAT@exlab\else \unskip\ \NAT@date\fi
       \else\@citea{\NAT@nm}\ \NAT@open\if\relax#1\relax\else#1\ \fi
         \NAT@date\fi
       \def\@citea{\NAT@close\NAT@sep\ }%
     \fi \hyper@natlinkend
     }}\ifNAT@swa\else\if\relax#2\relax\else\NAT@cmt\ #2\fi
     \NAT@close\fi}{#1}{#2}}

\def\NAT@citexnum[#1][#2]#3#4{\let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#4\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{\NAT@sep\penalty\@m\NAT@space}%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \@ifundefined{#3@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
    \write\csname #3@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}}%A
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{%
{\reset@font\bfseries?}
        \NAT@citeundefined\PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
     {\NAT@parse{\@citeb}\hbox{\hyper@natlinkstart{\@citeb}%
      \NAT@num\hyper@natlinkend}}}}{#1}{#2}}

\renewcommand\citeauthor[2]{%
\@ifundefined{#1@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
\write\csname #1@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{#2}}}%
     \@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{%
       {\reset@font\bfseries ?}\NAT@citeundefined
            \PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `#2' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\NAT@parse{#2}\ifx\NAT@noname\NAT@name
         {\reset@font\bfseries(author?)}\PackageWarning{natbib}
           {Author undefined for citation `#2'
             \MessageBreak
            on page \thepage}\else
         {\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\NAT@name\hyper@natlinkend}\fi}%
}

\renewcommand\citeyear[2]{%
\@ifundefined{#1@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
\write\csname #1@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{#2}}}%
     \@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{%
       {\reset@font\bfseries ?}\NAT@citeundefined
            \PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `#2' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\NAT@parse{#2}\if\relax\NAT@date\relax
         {\reset@font\bfseries(year?)}\PackageWarning{natbib}
           {Year undefined for citation `#2'
             \MessageBreak
            on page \thepage}\else
         {\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\NAT@date\hyper@natlinkend}\fi}%
}

\renewcommand\citefullauthor[2]{%
\@ifundefined{#1@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
\write\csname #1@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{#2}}}%
     \@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{%
       {\reset@font\bfseries ?}\NAT@citeundefined
            \PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `#2' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\NAT@parse{#2}\ifx\NAT@noname\NAT@all@names
         {\reset@font\bfseries(author?)}\PackageWarning{natbib}
           {Author undefined for citation `#2'
             \MessageBreak
            on page \thepage}\else
         {\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\NAT@all@names\hyper@natlinkend}\fi}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{biblio1}{goossens93}

\citet{biblio1}{goossens93}

\citep{biblio1}{goossens93}

\citealp{biblio1}{goossens93}

\citeauthor{biblio1}{goossens93}

\citeyear{biblio1}{goossens93}

\citefullauthor{biblio1}{goossens93}

\bibliographystyle{biblio1}{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio1}{bibexample}{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And I realise this was written based on a 1997 version of `natbib.sty` which I managed to find through Google.  On the plus-side the example I compiled did use the latest (2010) `natbib.sty` and worked... will try to update the relevant parts of my answer when I've got time to study the current version of `natbib.sty` more thoroughly.

Comment: I tried `Biblatex` but I encountered the strong drawback that we cannot use a custom style with it (as answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96958/switching-to-biblatex-how-to-load-custom-elsarticle-harv-bst-style)) so I'm back to the starting point with the same dilemna. How can I have multiple bibliographies with natbib and custom style?

Answer (score 0):

`Multibbl` and `natbib` do no coexist. `Biblatex` does not allow a custom style.

So I finally opted for `chapterbib` which best meets my main requirements (multiple bibliographies, using natbib and custom styles) even if it also has some drawbacks (I would notably have prefered a bibliography “tag” as `Multibbl` or two tags `\begin{refsection}` and `\end{refsection}` as `Biblatex`)

Edit: I have just found out that `Chapterbib` also allows tags (`\begin{cbunit}` and `\end{cbunit}`) instead of `\include`  so it's a good choice

Comment: I wouldn't say "`biblatex` does not allow a custom style", rather the contrary, it is likely the most customizable alternative. See, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/105447.

Comment: Biblatex simply doesn't use `.bst` files to set the style, Biblatex is more powerful and can do everything BibTeX can and more, but if the BibTeX style you want has not been "translated" to Biblatex then you will have to manually set up the style in Biblatex (which should be simpler than creating an entirely new `bst` mind).

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for those comments. In my case I indeed already have several .bst files ready to use, hence my choice to not create them from scratch for Biblatex. But good to know.